# 'default argument': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::initializer_list'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, c++14

I have the following

function in VS 15:

```
void get(std::initializer_list<std::tuple<int,bool>> props = {{1,true},{1,true}})
{}
```

which outputs:

**'default argument': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::initializer_list'**

What is wrong here?
I dont even get the error message? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably a MSVC bug?

Comment: This compiles fine for me on VS15. Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.

Comment: Can't reproduce with [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ss85UEdG2BKpZHnV).

Answer (score 3):

I bet you're receiving this error

> error C2440: 'default argument': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::initializer_list<std::tuple<int,bool>>'

because you didn't include

```
#include <tuple>
```

This is arguably a *not-very-explicative* error message. Make sure to include all of the other headers that are needed (like `<initializer_list>`) as well.

Comment: also don't forget to  `#include <initializer_list>`